# what can you say about two exactly same neural networks after training on same dataset?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, stochastic

Supposed you have two convolutional neural networks [implemented in matlab](https://it.mathworks.com/help/nnet/examples/create-simple-deep-learning-network-for-classification.html) and composed by these layers:

- imageInputLayer
- ConvolutionalLayer
- maxPoolinglayer
- relulayer
- softmaxlayer
- fullyconnectedlayer
- classification layer

Both of these networks have exactly same architecture. 
I apply the same method of training for 2 networks with same hyperparameters. 
Both of these networks have exactly same weights in their corresponding layers.

That is, both of these networks are a replica of each other.

Both of these networks are trained using exactly same training set and validation set without shuffle.

I am wondering:

- Will the scores (training error and validation error) and trained weights be different for both?
- Does it depend upon the method for training?

Comment: Why not try and see?

Answer (score 0):

In short: Yes to both - because inital weights are usually initated using random numbers.

A tad less short: A neural network is simply an algorithm, if there is no noise (i.e. randomness) introduced in any function on the way, 2 networks will end up being completely the same.